# Fetch value from server upon loading the window

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I want it to load as soon as I open the window after fetching the data from the server side.

Here's the HTML:

```
    <body>
        <h1> Just another counter </h1>
        <div class="count-area">
            <button type="button" onClick="increment()"> + </button>
            <button type="button" onClick="decrement()"> - </button>
            <p>Count: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the client side javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
  fetch("/").then(response => response.json()).then(data => document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = data['clicks']);
};

function increment() {
  fetch("/increment").then(response => response.json()).then(data => document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = data['clicks']);

};

function decrement() {
  fetch("/decrement").then(response => response.json()).then(data => document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = data['clicks']);
  };
```

Once the increment decrement buttons are pressed then the correct count shows up, but until then it remains 0.

Comment: The problem is that the fetch  during onload is either failing or returning zero.  To test, change the url to one that you know works, e.g., /increment or /decrement.  Also check the dev console (F12) for code and network errors.

Comment: I get this error in the dev console: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using windows.onload try using `onload="myFunction()"` on body :

```js
function clicksLoad() {
  fetch("/").then(response => response.json()).then(data => document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = data['clicks']);
};

function increment() {
  fetch("/increment").then(response => response.json()).then(data => document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = data['clicks']);

};

function decrement() {
  fetch("/decrement").then(response => response.json()).then(data => document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = data['clicks']);
  };
```

```html
<body onload="clicksLoad()">
  <h1>Just another counter</h1>
  <div class="count-area">
    <button type="button" onClick="increment()">+</button>
    <button type="button" onClick="decrement()">-</button>
    <p>Count: <a id="clicks"></a></p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This change will not fix the problem as the code executes the same way as the original.

Comment: @Yogi There is a difference between window.onload and onload event in particular element. For reference you can read here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-window-onload-and-body-onload/#:~:text=Windows%20onload%3A%20This%20window's%20onload,the%20right%20choice%20to%20use.

Comment: This doesn't work either.